# "Online" validation with TensorFlow

Tags: python, validation, optimization, tensorflow

My data is a set of matches and outcomes, listed chronologically. Normally, for purposes of "offline" validation, I'd run something like this to test how well my algorithm works:

```
# train
for matches_batch, outcomes_bach in train_data:
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={matches: matches_batch, outcomes: outcomes_batch})

# offline validation (just compute accuracy on test set)
test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={matches: test_matches, outcomes: test_outcomes})
print 'test accuracy = {:.2%}'.format(test_accuracy)
```

However, in the real world. Things would be done "online", where I train on a bunch of matches offline, and then every time I predict a new match, I also update my model parameters by running the optimizer using the outcome, like this:

```
# train
for matches_batch, outcomes_bach in train_data:
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={matches: matches_batch, outcomes: outcomes_batch})

# online validation (update accuracy and model with each new data point)
test_accuracy = 0.0
for match, outcome in zip(test_matches, test_outcomes):
    _, acc = sess.run([optimizer, accuracy], feed_dict={matches: [match], outcomes: [outcome])
    test_accuracy += acc / len(test_matches)
print 'test accuracy = {:.2%}'.format(test_accuracy)
```

The problem is that the above implementation of online testing (which is part of the validation scheme [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Olivier_Delalleau/publication/260709076_Beyond_Skill_Rating_Advanced_Matchmaking_in_Ghost_Recon_Online/links/550f4e8c0cf21287416b048b.pdf)) is slow.

Is there a way to speed up online validation like this with tensorflow?

Comment: @user1735003 They are not interchangeable. The first one is only trained on the training data, the second version retrains itself with every data point in the test data set after evaluating whether or not it predicted it right, which is more reflective of a real-world scenario.

Comment: @user1735003 The validation steps are not computing the same thing. The validation accuracy in version 1 is lower and less realistic than version 2 because version 2 improves its parameters after every data point--notice that the session also runs the optimizer during the validation step in version 2, which doesn't happen in version 1.

Answer (score 0):

After having a quick look at the paper, here is what I think:

- They update their model with a few (number unknown) samples, rather than one -- one could say they take enough samples to fill a minibatch.
- They then validate on one fold.

What it means with respect to your implementation:

- You don't need to retrain online on the entire fold, just on a minibatch
- You don't have to compute the validation accuracy one sample at a time, take whichever approach is faster (minibatches, or even the whole dataset as in your code if you can afford it).

Both points above should speed up things significantly.

Finally, don't use test in lieu of validation, especially when it involves training on it.

Comment: I do have to update the model parameters after every match, so this won't work. They do the same thing in their paper: "The algorithm is first trained on a training set (this is the “offline training” phase described in Section III-C), then its performance is evaluated on a disjoint test dataset
while also **updating parameters after each test match result**
(“online update” phase). "

Comment: Yes, and I also see "*we recover from the database the composition of the last few matches of all players involved in the match that just ended. The number of matches to recover needs to be validated* (..)". It seems to me they are not using a single sample.

Comment: Regardless of whether I use just the latest match or the last `n` matches of all players involved in the latest match, this answer doesn't help speed up the online validation step because the model parameters still need to be updated after each new match during the online update phase.

Comment: Again, in the article, the online update happens on a minibatch only. How can this not be a speed-up compared to retraining on the entire validation set?

Comment: They also go through the entire validation set. The difference being: for each match in the validation set, they also draw from the last `n` matches from all players in that match. I don't do that because it is too costly of a database query. So, if there are `k` matches in the validation set, then they are running `k` updates on minibatches of size `n`, whereas I am running `k` updates on a single match. I'm sorry, but none of your comments or your answer have been helpful. It seems like all you're trying to do is undermine my question because you don't understand it.

Comment: Their online update is on a small minibatch only. Then they go through a fold (Fold 2 in Fig.6), but that is for evaluation, not for training. (Note the difference with your approach, where you do both on the same set). I am sorry that you do not understand anything I am saying to help you. This is my last comment.